# why does subprocess fails during the given task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, operating-system, subprocess

I am using subprocess instead of os.system to execute a shell command to convert a document to pdf asynchronously. When being called repeatedly, it fails for approx 50% of files. It doesn't convert the doc file to pdf. How can I fix it.

```
conversion_process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell( 'soffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_' + author  + ' --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ' + folder + ' ' + input_file, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = await conversion_process.communicate()
   if stderr:
       app.logger.error(f"stderr: {stderr}")
```

error message:

```
stderr: b'javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common
is installed.
If it is already installed then try removing ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/javasettings_Linux_*.xml
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

Comment: Could you please share the error message for failure

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili, I have added error message in my question above.

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili, But i have a doubt, if error message mentioned above is the reason, then why other commands are executing successfully. They should also have thrown this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error message is because the path variable used by the subprocess and passed to LibreOffice is not sufficient to find the JRE. I ran into this same issue and changed it to the following which seems to fix it.

```
subprocess.run(cmd,env={'HOME':'/home/username'})
```

I can likewise confirm that this error does not happen every time it is called, my speculation as to why this occurs is that JRE is only needed for some document conversions, not all.